# tcpdump is not capturing any packets for host

Tags: networking, tcpdump

Here is the output of the `ip addr` command:

[image: Screenshot of the ip addr command]

I tried out this command for showing network  traffic:

```
 sudo tcpdump -n host google.com
```

But it's giving output like this:

```
tcpdump: WARNING: eth0: no IPv4 address assigned  
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode  
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

I also pinged google.com, but it is still showing no packets.

Comment: If tcpdump says that there's no IPv4 address assigned to eth0 then you might have a bad network configuration. What does `ip addr` say?

Comment: ip addr, is showing all 3 interfaces i.e lo, eth0, wlan0

Comment: Nothing more? What about IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, it also showing the ip addresses ..

Comment: i tried tcpdump -D, it showing bluetooth0 - is it beacuse of bluetooth device problem ?

Comment: Can you please post the complete output of `ip addr` and `route`?

Comment: i posted the screen shot(ss) of ip addr, plz check that

Answer (score 2):

You haven't assigned an IP address to your `eth0`. So `tcpdump` and `ping` cannot work via `eth0`.

So either assign one if you are connected to a wired network or use your `wlan0` interface instead.

E.g. `ping -I wlan0 www.google.com` or `tcpdump -i wlan0 -n host google.com`.

Comment: okay i got it, but after using wlan0 interface in ping, should i do any change in tcpdump command

Comment: You can also try to specify the interface (see the edit above).

Comment: Thanks alot, i got i and assigned tcpdump to wlan0 interface also, now it can listen on wlan0 and packets are capturing.